# Constraint Layout measures incorrect height if it is nested into scrollview

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

///Content

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

In this case constraint layout to long. I also have problem with marginEnd of child views. I have a lot of child views similar to

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDurationPlan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_small"
            style="@style/WhiteTextViewStyle"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tvPlanLabel"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPlanLabel"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            tools:text="TextView" />
```

and layout_marginEnd doesn't work.
Please help me!

Comment: What version of Constraint Layout are you using? Have you updated to the latest version?

Comment: Yes, I use 1.0.2

Comment: Hi @IhorKucherenko, did you find a solution for the height issue? I am having the same problem with a ConstraintLayout (v1.0.2) inside a Scrollview and it creates a large empty space below the CL that is scrollable. It disappears if the ScrollView is removed.

Comment: Hi @DavidWhitman, no. I had to do some hack. I got location of last view and set this value to height of constraint layout

Answer (score 1):

as I could say, this bug was fixed in com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3

Answer (score 0):

To solve problem with marginEnd we have to use android:layout_width="0dp" for child views

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I get location of the last view and set this value to height of constraint layout

```
private void adjustConstraintLayoutToView(View view) {
    final ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (mConstraintLayout.getMeasuredHeight() > 0) {
                int[] location = new int[2];
                view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
                mConstraintLayout.getLayoutParams().height = location[1];
                mConstraintLayout.requestLayout();
                if (vto.isAlive()) {
                    vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```